# Making a new library with javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

how can we make simple library like jquery through javascript?
i want to use my functions that can be used the functions like **animate** in javascript

Comment: did i misunderstood your question ? do you want a library like jquery or want to write extension methods in jquery , if you want the first way , i will delete my answer.

Comment: yaa.i want to  write my own library.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that a very good tutorial is http://www.mikedoesweb.com

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to write library similar to jquery

see this good video

http://ejohn.org/blog/building-a-javascript-library/

```
You can write you jquery extensions as below
```

for example i wrote the below one few days back

```
jQuery.fn.centerElement = function () {
        trace('trying to center');
        this.css("position","relative");
        var parentObj = $(this).parent();
        this.css("top", ( parentObj.height() - this.height() ) / 2 + "px");
        this.css("left", ( parentObj.width() - this.width() ) / 2 + "px");
        return this;
    };
```

you can use as below

```
$('#divid').centerElement();
```

Comment: ya thats gud.bt i am saying that no extensions of jquery.suppose in animate function i want to add opacity field then how can i make my own function so that many css properties can be added

Comment: i mean i am doing work on the prototype function(properties,id or class).now it takes the properties and add it into css when any event occurs like onclick.

Answer (score 0):

the best example to make library is given [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-your-first-javascript-library/)